# How to properly use future builder inside a column

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i'm using a future builder inside my column widget( i have other widgets sadly ).

Here is my code :

```
FutureBuilder(
                      future: loadStudent(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {


                          return (snapshot.data.student)
                              .map<Widget>((std) => StudentProfile(
                                  std.StudentName,
                                  std.StudentPicture,
                                  std.speciality,


                                  std.badge))
                              .toList();
                        } else {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      }),
```

well it throws this error:

type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'.

I understand what the error mean ( basicly column takes individual widgets as children ) , yet i don't know how to fix it . 
Please note that i tried to use  the '...' operator in my return statement it threw another error :

Expected an identifier, but got '...'

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a List of Widget instead of a Widget.

You need to put your List on a Column Widget like this :

```
List students = (snapshot.data.student)
    .map<Widget>((std) => StudentProfile(
        std.StudentName,
        std.StudentPicture,
        std.speciality,
        std.badge)).toList();

return Column(
    children: students,
)
```